# Make entire DIV clickable except the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the entire DIV clickable and got it working. However, I want to make an exception to the dropdown menu. Clicking this dropdown `button` shouldn't open up `next.html`. It currently opens up the dropdown but also quickly opens up `next.html`. How do I go about this?

[Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/40wntLyo/](https://jsfiddle.net/40wntLyo/)

```
<div class="project__body" onclick="location.href='next.html';">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h1>Title of the DIV</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `event.stopPropogation()` on your drop-down to stop the bubbling of events up the Dom tree

Comment: How? This is a bootstrap 4 dropdown menu. I didn't write any JS for it.

Comment: `$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(event){event.stopPropogation})` should work

Comment: Didn't work. JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/25zhsywf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet should work

Move the click event to the parent dropdown container and it will also prevent redirection on click of dropdown items

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function(event) {
  $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").toggle()
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="project__body" onclick="location.href='next.html';">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h1>Title of the DIV!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing you have to remove inline javascript event and try below exmaple:

jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
})
$('.project__body').click(function(){
   window.location.href="next.html"
})
```

html:

```
<div class="project__body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h1>Title of the DIV!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p>There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. There's more content here in this div. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used the other solution by Immortal Dude.

Answer (score 1):

Add a JS function to the dropdown's parent div which is called on click:

```
<div class="col-2 text-right" onclick="processClick()">
  // Dropdown content here
</div>

<script>
    function processClick(e) { e.stopPropagation() }
</script>
```

Comment: Updated my question. There's more content in the DIV. The link must work if the user clicks anywhere on the DIV (except the dropdown).

Comment: Demo added https://jsfiddle.net/40wntLyo/ and it still opens up `next.html`